# Magento: Filter Configurable Product by their options

Tags: magento, filter

I want to filter some configurable products by attributes that are used to create more instances of that product (size, color etc.). This means those attributes are not directly assigned to the configurable product, but their childs.

I already have a code that filters configurable products by some attributes, but these are all assigned to the main product, and the children inherit that: designer.

```
$attributes_designers = $this->getRequest()->getParam('designers');   
$attributes_colors = $this->getRequest()->getParam('color');
$attributes_sizes = $this->getRequest()->getParam('size');



$currentCategory =  Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory(); 
$_productCollection = $currentCategory->getProductCollection();

if(count($attributes_designers)>0 and !in_array("ALL",$attributes_designers)) {        
    $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('designer',$attributes_designers);
}
if(count($attributes_colors)>0 and !in_array("ALL",$attributes_colors)) {        
    $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('color',$attributes_colors);
}
if(count($attributes_sizes)>0 and !in_array("ALL",$attributes_sizes)) {        
    $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('size_apparel_eu',$attributes_sizes);
}
if(isset($_GET['order'])) $_productCollection->setOrder($this->getRequest()->getParam('order'), $this->getRequest()->getParam('dir'));

 $_productCollection->load();
```

here, the `color`, and `size_apparel_eu`, are not working, because those are not directly assigned to the product, but their children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly here...You first need to get the child products with something like this:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_configurable_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable');
$_child_products = array();
if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable')
  $_child_products = $_configurable_model->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
```

Then you can use some sort of loop (foreach is handy)

```
foreach ($_child_products as $_child_product){
    $_child_product->getRequest()->getParam('designers');
}
```

Or however you need to call those methods to get the child product information.

I hope this was helpful and relevent!